# Using a PushButton as a trigger in Arduino

Tags: button, arduino

I'm trying to work with a simple Arduino circuit that increments a counter variable on pressing a push button in the circuit (connected as INPUT to PIN 8). My code is as simple as follows:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int c = 0, btnPIN, btnVal;

void setup ()
{
    btnPIN = 8;
    pinMode(btnPIN, INPUT); 

    lcd.begin(16,2);
    lcd.clear();
}
void void loop()
{
    btnVal = digitalRead(btnPIN);
    if (btnVal == LOW)
    {
        c++;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print(c);
    }
}
```

Problem is the counter increases by more than 1 every time I push the button. A little bit of printing on the serial monitor indicates that each time the button is pressed and the voltage is LOW, the conditional code is executed multiple times and the counter increases by multiple times instead of 1.

Maybe, I need to write some logic that checks if the button was initially unpressed, then pushed and then released again and then these steps would trigger the required action.

The solution I'm currently working with is as under (which works just fine):

```
int btnStatus = 0;
void loop()
{
    btnVal = digitalRead(btnPIN);

    if (btnVal == LOW)
        btnStatus = 1;
    if(btnStatus == 1 && btnVal == HIGH)    
    {
        c++;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print(c);
        btnStatus = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a simpler solution available or if this approach is wrong for other reasons? Any advice would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, you need to track the previous state of the button to know if it is a new press or if it is simply being held down. Your code could be rewritten to look more like a state machine, however:

```
typedef enum {
    BTN_STATE_RELEASED,
    BTN_STATE_PRESSED
} ButtonState;

ButtonState btnStatus = BTN_STATE_RELEASED;

void increment_counter()
{
    c++;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(c);
}

void loop()
{
    btnVal = digitalRead(btnPIN);

    switch(btnStatus)
    {
    case BTN_STATE_PRESSED:
        // Handle button release
        if(btnVal == HIGH)
        {
            btnStatus = BTN_STATE_RELEASED;
        }

        break;

    case BTN_STATE_RELEASED:
        // Handle button press
        if(btnVal == LOW)
        {
            increment_counter();
            btnStatus = BTN_STATE_PRESSED;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This was rewritten to use an enum to track the state of the system (a bit overkill for a simple button, but an important concept to know in case your system grows more complex).

The code to update the display was also moved into its own function to make it better separated between the display change and the actual update of the state.

Comment: Thank you! This approach looks like a cleaner and organized way of getting things done as the circuit gets more complicated. I'm actually going to be using three buttons so this is going to help!

Answer (score 2):

Another problem you you may be having is that mechanical buttons [bounce](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/debouncing). That is, they jump between two positions several times quickly before settling to a final position. This is standard operation so it is necessary to "debounce" the button.

There are very many ways to do this, but [Here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce) is a tutorial using an Arduino.

The main issue, as you probably figured out, is that the `loop` function is getting called multiple times while the button is down. This is what is fixed by your code, and yours looks to be a good solution and I don't really see a simpler way. For another way, though, perhaps you could try just adding a call to `delay` at the end of `loop` to slow it down a bit. You would have to play with the delay amount a bit, but it could work. Really though, your solution looks just fine.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the bounce issue.

Comment: The simplest switch debounce is to use good old hardware. Just add a 1µF capacitor across the switch and you're done ; )

See the classic switch tutorial series http://www.gammon.com.au/switches